# С чего начать для программирования на jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Вообще у меня такой вопрос. Я изучал html + css. В общем, хочу стать хорошим веб-программистом. Хочу программировать на jQuery. Подскажите, с чего начать.

Comment: с javascript`а, но вот хорошая ознакомительная статья:

[jQuery – Javascript нового поколения](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/inet/jQuery.xml)

Comment: Сначала добавьте `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>` в начало тега `<head></head>`.

Comment: а вот это плохой совет! скрипты должны располагаться **в конце** документа

Comment: Спасибо за статью! А еще такой вопрос. Мне советовали посмотреть видеоуроки "Специалист" 
Что скажете? Имеет смысл?

Comment: @Spectre, с `.ready()` это не имеет значения, а включают библиотеки и т.д. обычно всё-таки в хэде) но это больше шутка была)

Comment: @Spectre, главное, не должны валяться на сторонних ресурсах. =)

Comment: Kremchik, имеет. =) Например, поисковые роботы могут загрузить страницу, не отвлекаясь на скрипты, а устройства, которые JS не очень уважают, типа некоторых мобильников, вообще не будут заморачиваться.

Comment: с другой стороны, в идела лучше использовать AMD

Comment: @Spectre, нет, INTEL!!! :))))))))))))

Comment: @knes, jQuery должен валяться на стороннем ресурсе... это предпочтительней, чем кидать его себе - в этом никакого смысла нет.

Comment: @Kremchik, всегда так делал, пока однажды не "умер" провайдер и инета не было 11 дней. В веб проект как раз и работал с глобальной jQuery library и без неё никак не работал...11 дней простоя, как итог. Снова вы даете плохой совет...к сожалению.

Comment: @Asen, это не я советы такие даю... Среди сайтов, которые прислушиваются к "моему" совету php.net, opera.com и многие другие, специализирующиеся на разработке веб-приложений и смежных темах. Шанс того, что майкрософтский или гугловский цдн ляжет не велик, согласитесь. О преимуществах такого подхода почитайте.

Comment: Просто слова "валяться на сторонних ресурсах" звучат не к месту. Лежать в CDN - так правильней, да. Ну а если вы в локальном проекте используете внешние ресурсы - то ССЗБ. Так-то!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начать, однозначно, с сайта [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Инфа 100%. Там прямо на главной есть то, с чего начать.

> (Learn jQuery Now!)

Плюс - там довольно понятная документация.

Если на английском читать тяжело, начать с изучения английского.

Comment: А такой еще вопрос. Сколько по врмени нужно,чтобы изучить JS?

Comment: js очень глубокий язык, разберитесь с this, замыканиями, неявном приведении типов, цепочками прототипов и посмотрите сколько на это уйдёт времени

Comment: @Spectre все-таки очень злобен и страшен. =)
Не пугайте так человека, он подумает, что 30 лет и три года...
Реально, если этим заняться вплотную, то около 2х лет.

Comment: @knes Благодарю) 
А такой вопрос. Вот мне очень интересно делать сайты. 
Да и вроде веб-программисты ценятся очень. Такой вопрос сайты же можно делать только на jquery или я что-то путаю? Если да,то сколько примерно учиться нужно,чтобы с ней хорошо взаимодествовать?

Comment: вот когда сможете написать собственный аналог хорошего годного фреймворка/библиотеки, можно будет сказать, что ваше обучение закончено

Comment: Чисто на jquery вы сайт, скорее всего не напишете.
На jquery/css/html можете написать вряд ли что-то серьезнее, в прикладном плане, игрушек, типа, colorschemedesigner.
Но верстальщиком вас с радостью возьмут. Клепать красивые интерфейсы с рюшечками, бегающими окошечками и ползунками.

Для полноценного сайта придется либо изучить серверную технологию(хоть одну), либо отобрать у гугла V8, точнее ее модификацию для сервера.

Comment: Просто интересует,через сколько примерно можно начать делать неплохие сайты )

Comment: @knes, всё-таки верстальщик и client-side/frontend developer - разные вещи

@Сяськаа, это останеться тайной пока вы не сделаете неплохой сайт(прям как с котом Шрёдингера), т.к. вы можете это сделать и прямо сейчас, а можете вообще никогда не сделать

Answer (score 7):

Я просто оставлю это здесь: [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/).

Comment: а я позволю себе дорисовать еще вот это: [tuts+](http://learnjquery.tutsplus.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, и конечно же, **http://jquery-docs.ru**...

Comment: Ничего не конечно. Не знаешь английский - вали из программирования! Если, разумеется, не считать програмирование 1С - программированием. 

Про вали - это не конкретно вам, а вообще, тем кто не знает. Лучше "сызмальства" приучать людей к хорошим практикам, ящитаю.

Comment: Согласен =)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы) С англ.яз нет проблем)